# curl with https and xml load (filecrypt.cc)

Tags: xml, api, curl, https

Does anyone have any idea why this function does not work?

Using http://filecrypt.cc/api.pdf

```js
function fileCryptCcFolder($foldername){

    global $och_links;
    $api_auth_code = 'XXXXXXX';

$links = array($och_links);

// POST DATA
$postdata = array(
    'api_key' => $api_auth_code,
    'fn' => 'container',
        'sub' => 'create',
        'fmt' => 'xml',
        'foldername' => $foldername,
        'captcha' => '1',
        'allow_container' => '1',
        'allow_links' => '1',
    'mirror' => implode("\n", $links)
);


    // INITIALISE CURL REQUEST
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.filecrypt.cc/api.php');

    // CURL OPTIONS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    // EXECUTE CURL REQUEST
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    list($filecrypt_links) = explode("\n", $result);
    curl_close($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($filecrypt_links);
    return $xml;
}
```

The call is made so:

```
$filecrypt_links = fileCryptCcFolder($_POST['hashcode']);
```

**Error**:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bbcode\includes\functions.php on line 246
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string():  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bbcode\includes\functions.php on line 246
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bbcode\includes\functions.php on line 246

Please help :/

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: It should be handed over links to a container (folder).
Following the successful transfer, to the container-Link are displayed.
Like this: http://filecrypt.cc/Container/D92DDFC8H.html

Comment: That link you posted returns a 404 error for me. The problem right now is that you aren't obtaining a proper `xml` formatted object from your `curl_exec($ch);`. My guess is that you probably have something set up incorrectly in you `$postdata` in regards to `filecrypt.cc` api (api key perhaps?). Try doing a var_dump of `$result` to confirm this.

Comment: Work fine with
 $output = $data_array['container']['link'];
 return $output;

Comment: What is `$data_array`? that variable isn't declared in your provided code. You need to confirm that you're capturing properly formatted `xml` inside the variable `$filecrypt_links`

Comment: I have changed the full code with - Update Post #1

Comment: add it as an answer and accept it, good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Working Version**

```
function xml_to_array($xml, $main_heading = '')
{
    $deXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $deJson = json_encode($deXml);
    $xml_array = json_decode($deJson, TRUE);
    if (!empty($main_heading)) {
        $returned = $xml_array[$main_heading];
        return $returned;
    }
    else {
        return $xml_array;
    }
}

function fileCryptCcFolder($foldername)
{
    global $och_links;
    $links = array(
        $och_links
    );

    // POST DATA

    $postdata = array(
        'api_key' => '86a0321dc4c2b9c8ec563143a9db4df1439a05c0',
        'fn' => 'container',
        'sub' => 'create',
        'fmt' => 'xml',
        'foldername' => $foldername,
        'captcha' => '1',
        'allow_container' => '1',
        'allow_links' => '1',
        'mirror[]' => implode("\n", $links)
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.filecrypt.cc/api.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); //Setting post data as xml
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $filecrypt_links = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $xml = $filecrypt_links;
    $data_array = xml_to_array($xml);
    $output = $data_array['container']['link'];
    return $output;
}
```